# Painting on the margins of QScrollArea

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt5

I want to draw something like x\y axes scales like rules in Photoshop but with QScrollArea
There is good property for that:

```
QAbstractScrollArea::setViewportMargins(20,20,0,0)
```

and it works fine - there white space at the top and left sides and putting point to (0,0) draw it with specified offset.
But I cant draw at this place.
I tried

```
painter.drawLine(-10,0,-10,height())
```

but it do nothing. So how can I draw something on this margin space?

Answer (score 2):

You're painting on the viewport, and this won't work. You need to put a widget in the margin area and paint within that widget's `paintEvent`.

Comment: yes, indeed, I need to paint on the viewport. And I can do it without problem but in its area `(0,0,width(),height))`. But I want to make this margin area unaccesible. May be to shift painter origin ... I am going to try you advice but I think it will be a problems with viewport resizing or scaling ...

Comment: @folibis As I've said, to paint in the margin area, you can't be painting on the viewport! Viewport does not include the margins!